# mapbox storytelling click through div

Tags: javascript, css, z-index, pointer-events

There is a mapbox scrollytelling https://demos.mapbox.com/scrollytelling/. I need to acceess map(mouse click and mousemove), but can't access it. 
I have tried with `pointer-events:none` to parent layer(does not work for me, I applied it to almost every layer, but the map still does not receive the click event), but this one is fine but I need mouseover, mouseenter events too

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('e', e);
  map.fire("click", {
    lngLat: map.unproject([e.x, e.y]),
  });
});
```

And there is a `z-index:-5` for map layer, that affects click too somehow.
Actualy map.fire is fine, but how to pass mouseover, mouseenter etc.? Or any thoughts on pointer-events:none and z-index? All I need is to pass the evnts to map
Thanks

Comment: was `map.on('click', someClickCallback)` not working?

Comment: @Avocado map.on('click', someClickCallback) is not working.